# Connection refused : Failed to connect to ResourceManager:8032

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I'm trying to run word count program for first time on hadoop and i've started the hdfs service and created text file as input for the MapReducer , I've moved the file to hadoop file system

**I've used this command to run the code :**

```
hadoop jar '/home/cloudera/wordcount.jar' WordCount /inputnew/inputFile.txt /output_new/
```

And i get these errors :

```
cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop jar '/home/cloudera/wordcount.jar' WordCount /inputnew/inputFile.txt /output_new/
18/02/06 07:54:48 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032
18/02/06 07:54:49 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/06 07:54:50 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/06 07:54:51 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/06 07:54:52 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/06 07:54:53 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/06 07:54:54 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/06 07:54:55 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/06 07:54:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/06 07:54:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/06 07:54:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/06 07:54:58 WARN ipc.Client: Failed to connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032: retries get failed due to exceeded maximum allowed retries number: 10
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:744)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3000(Client.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1555)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getNewApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:217)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getNewApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate.getNewJobID(ResourceMgrDelegate.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getNewJobID(YARNRunner.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1304)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1325)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: Connection refused!

Comment: how I could resolve it ?!

Comment: Just because HDFS is working, doesn't mean YARN is. Your ResourceManager is not started. Use Cloudera Manager to check

Answer (score 0):

> Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:8032

It seems, your ResourceManager is not running or using different port. You could verify it

```
http://localhost:8088
```

Assuming, you have changed its port number as default port number for cloudera server is `7180`.

If your server is not running then, you could **[start cloudera server](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/manager/5-0-x/Cloudera-Manager-Introduction/cm5i_start_admin_console.html?scroll=cmug_topic_3_1)** using below command

```
$ sudo service cloudera-scm-server start
```

Comment: 8032 is not an HTTP port. I have fixed your answer. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cdh_ig_ports_cdh5.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for updating my answer. But, I was referring as per OP original question. (s)he seems to be using `8032` port number. Anyway, thanks again. :-)

Comment: The yarn-site defaults to 8032 for the resource manager, but `http://resource-manager-server:8032` will always be an error page. That's all